# Should 'Identify This Movie' answers have more than just a link?

Tags: discussion, reference, identify, answer-quality

[**This question**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/373/period-film-with-king-in-medical-contraption) is inspiring me to ask this.

Should the answers to these questions contain more than just a link and also have an explanation from the answerer of ***why*** they think it is the proper answer?

I think this may add more substance to these answers as well as give a better understanding for readers/original asker as to why this might be a possible selection for the question.

I do fear that this may spark either argument/opinion but obviously, that is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Questions **and** answers should always be more than just a link.  Identify qna should always have a breakdown of what's being identified.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule on Stack Exchange is that link only answers are bad. They might be good right now, but there is no guarantee that the external resource will not cease to exist at some point in the future.

The answer should at least contain the title of the identified media. I presume that if you come across such answer, editing it to contain the title would be a good practice. If the link is dead already, the answer should probably be flagged and removed.